# How to make Icon fit in Menu.Item in Semantic UI React Vertical Menu?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm building a vertical menu bar in Semantic UI React.  I have a number of Menu.Item components in my Menu.  The first Menu.Item contains an Icon component with no Menu text.  The issue I am having is that the Icon is overflowing into the Menu.Item below it.  I can't figure out why this is?  I have tried adjusting margin, padding, line-height but nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?  Would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

[image]

Here is my code for the first couple Menu.Items.  Adding text to Menu.Item increases the size correctly but I don't want any Menu text with the Icon.

```
<Menu.Item link><Icon name='x' size='large'/></Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item as={Link} to='/' onClick={this.handleSidebarHide}>
              Home
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item as={Link} to='/about' onClick={this.handleSidebarHide}>About Us</Menu.Item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This one it will help you

```
<Menu.Item> link style={{  display: "inline-block" }} ><Icon name='x' size='large'/></Menu.Item>
```

Comment: This along with adding width: 100% solved my problem.  Thanks!